# Merge date ranges

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle SQL newbie here and first time poster.

I thought this would be simple until I realized I can't figure out how to split return assignments.

Here is my assignments table: ASGN

```
ID  ST_DT       END_DT      POS    LOCN  STATUS  WAGE_CD
--  ----------  ----------  -----  ----  ------  -------
A   12-31-2006  08-16-2009  CLERK  LAX   3       A
A   08-17-2009  10-04-2009  CLERK  LAX   0       Z
A   10-05-2009  06-30-2010  OPR    NYC   3       A
A   07-01-2010  12-31-2010  OPR    NYC   3       B
A   01-01-2011  06-30-2012  OPR    NYC   3       C
A   07-01-2012  04-09-2013  OPR    NYC   3       D
A   04-10-2013  06-30-2013  CLERK  LAX   3       A
A   07-01-2013  08-10-2014  CLERK  LAX   3       B
A   07-01-2013  08-10-2014  CLERK  LAX   3       C
B   04-10-2013  05-31-2013  SUP    LAX   3       A
B   06-01-2013  06-30-2014  SUP    LAX   0       Z
B   07-01-2013  08-10-2014  SUP    LAX   3       B
B   08-11-2014  08-11-2014  CLERK  NYC   3       A
B   08-12-2014  01-11-2015  SUP    LAX   3       A
B   01-12-2015  02-10-2016  SUP    LAX   3       B
B   02-11-2016  08-12-2016  OPER   SFO   3       A
B   02-11-2016  08-12-2016  OPER   SFO   3       B
```

I've already tried this below with unexpected results.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT ID
         ,MIN(ST_DT) ST_DT
         ,MAX(END_DT) END_DT
         ,POS
         ,LOCN
         ,STATUS
   FROM ASGN
   GROUP BY ID, LOCN, POS, STATUS
) SUBQRY
ORDER BY ID, ST_DT
```

Unexpected results, but makes sense. This is where return assignments are not separated by combined with previous assignments.

```
ID  ST_DT       END_DT      POS    LOCN  STATUS
--  ----------  ----------  -----  ----  ------
A   12-31-2006  08-10-2014  CLERK  LAX   3
A   08-17-2009  10-04-2009  CLERK  LAX   0
A   10-05-2009  04-09-2010  OPR    NYC   3
B   04-10-2013  02-10-2015  SUP    LAX   3
B   06-01-2013  06-30-2014  SUP    LAX   0
B   08-11-2014  08-11-2014  CLERK  NYC   3
B   02-11-2016  08-12-2016  OPER   SFO   3
```

And the results I would like to see where the adjacent dates are combined per ID, POSition, LOCatioN, and STATUS:

```
ID  ST_DT       END_DT      POS    LOCN  STATUS
--  ----------  ----------  -----  ----  ------
A   12-31-2006  08-16-2009  CLERK  LAX   3
A   08-17-2009  10-04-2009  CLERK  LAX   0
A   10-05-2009  04-09-2010  OPR    NYC   3
A   04-10-2013  08-10-2014  CLERK  LAX   3
B   04-10-2013  05-31-2013  SUP    LAX   3
B   06-01-2013  06-30-2014  SUP    LAX   0
B   07-01-2013  08-10-2014  SUP    LAX   3
B   08-11-2014  08-11-2014  CLERK  NYC   3
B   08-12-2014  02-10-2015  SUP    LAX   3
B   02-11-2016  08-12-2016  OPER   SFO   3
```

I asked a more season Oracle SQL programmer and he said I'd have to us PLSQL, but I'm thinking there has to be a way to make this work via SQL.

Test setup script:

```
create table asgn
(id varchar2(10)
,st_dt date
,end_dt date
,pos varchar2(10)
,locn varchar2(10)
,status number
,wage_cd varchar2(10));

insert into asgn values('A',to_date('12-31-2006','mm-dd-yyyy'),to_date('08-16-2009','mm-dd-yyyy'),'CLERK','LAX',3,'A');
insert into asgn values('A',to_date('08-17-2009','mm-dd-yyyy'),to_date('10-04-2009','mm-dd-yyyy'),'CLERK','LAX',0,'Z');
insert into asgn values('A',to_date('10-05-2009','mm-dd-yyyy'),to_date('06-30-2010','mm-dd-yyyy'),'OPR','NYC',3,'A');
insert into asgn values('A',to_date('07-01-2010','mm-dd-yyyy'),to_date('12-31-2010','mm-dd-yyyy'),'OPR','NYC',3,'B');
insert into asgn values('A',to_date('01-01-2011','mm-dd-yyyy'),to_date('06-30-2012','mm-dd-yyyy'),'OPR','NYC',3,'C');
insert into asgn values('A',to_date('07-01-2012','mm-dd-yyyy'),to_date('04-09-2013','mm-dd-yyyy'),'OPR','NYC',3,'D');
insert into asgn values('A',to_date('04-10-2013','mm-dd-yyyy'),to_date('06-30-2013','mm-dd-yyyy'),'CLERK','LAX',3,'A');
insert into asgn values('A',to_date('07-01-2013','mm-dd-yyyy'),to_date('08-10-2014','mm-dd-yyyy'),'CLERK','LAX',3,'B');
insert into asgn values('A',to_date('07-01-2013','mm-dd-yyyy'),to_date('08-10-2014','mm-dd-yyyy'),'CLERK','LAX',3,'C');
insert into asgn values('B',to_date('04-10-2013','mm-dd-yyyy'),to_date('05-31-2013','mm-dd-yyyy'),'SUP','LAX',3,'A');
insert into asgn values('B',to_date('06-01-2013','mm-dd-yyyy'),to_date('06-30-2014','mm-dd-yyyy'),'SUP','LAX',0,'Z');
insert into asgn values('B',to_date('07-01-2013','mm-dd-yyyy'),to_date('08-10-2014','mm-dd-yyyy'),'SUP','LAX',3,'B');
insert into asgn values('B',to_date('08-11-2014','mm-dd-yyyy'),to_date('08-11-2014','mm-dd-yyyy'),'CLERK','NYC',3,'A');
insert into asgn values('B',to_date('08-12-2014','mm-dd-yyyy'),to_date('01-11-2015','mm-dd-yyyy'),'SUP','LAX',3,'A');
insert into asgn values('B',to_date('01-12-2015','mm-dd-yyyy'),to_date('02-10-2016','mm-dd-yyyy'),'SUP','LAX',3,'B');
insert into asgn values('B',to_date('02-11-2016','mm-dd-yyyy'),to_date('08-12-2016','mm-dd-yyyy'),'OPER','SFO',3,'A');
insert into asgn values('B',to_date('02-11-2016','mm-dd-yyyy'),to_date('08-12-2016','mm-dd-yyyy'),'OPER','SFO',3,'B');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Employee A has two rows for 07-01-2013 through 08-10-2014; I assumed that is a mistake and I deleted one of the rows.

Other than that, this is an application of the "tabibitosan method" for solving "gaps and islands" problems for date ranges. The trick is in creating the "groups" (`gp`) for adjacent intervals.

```
with
     prep ( id, st_dt, end_dt, gp, pos, locn, status ) as (
       select id, st_dt, end_dt, 
              end_dt - sum( end_dt - st_dt + 1 ) over (partition by id, pos, locn, status 
                                                       order by st_dt),
              pos, locn, status
       from   asgn
     )
select id, min(st_dt) as st_dt, max(end_dt) as end_dt, pos, locn, status
from   prep
group by id, gp, pos, locn, status
order by id, st_dt
;



ID         ST_DT      END_DT     POS        LOCN           STATUS
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
A          12-31-2006 08-16-2009 CLERK      LAX                 3
A          08-17-2009 10-04-2009 CLERK      LAX                 0
A          10-05-2009 04-09-2013 OPR        NYC                 3
A          04-10-2013 08-10-2014 CLERK      LAX                 3
B          04-10-2013 05-31-2013 SUP        LAX                 3
B          06-01-2013 06-30-2014 SUP        LAX                 0
B          07-01-2013 08-10-2014 SUP        LAX                 3
B          08-11-2014 08-11-2014 CLERK      NYC                 3
B          08-12-2014 02-10-2016 SUP        LAX                 3
B          02-11-2016 08-12-2016 OPER       SFO                 3

 10 rows selected
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you!  
  As for the Employee A with two rows, I wanted to show there was a difference between WAGE_CD between the two.  I could've added another level of information in the table, but did not want to confuse any further.  
    
Now, I just have to figure out the ORA-01841: (full) year... error that I'm receiving.